# Javascript prototype functionality guidance

Tags: javascript, node.js

My Code is below:

```
*****************

var Person = function (name, yearOfBirth, job) {
this.name = name,
this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth,
this.job = job
}

Person.prototype.age = function () {
return (2020 - this.yearOfBirth)
}

Person.prototype.fullName = function () {
return `${this.name} great`
}
    Person.prototype.car = function () {
if (this.age < 18) {
    return ('Dude u still need to get older to drive')
} else {
    return ('You are eligible for a license')
}
}


Person.prototype.medals =  "silver"
var john = new Person('John',2010,'Teacher')
console.log(john.name)
console.log(john.age())
console.log(john.fullName())
console.log(john.medals)
console.log(john.car())


Output:
John
10
John great
silver
You are eligible for a license
*****************
```

Now if you would see although John Age is just 10 years the ideal output should be "he needs to get older" but it is just returning the else statement or is my understanding on prototype wrong??

Thank you

How can i access the Objects Prototype in another function??

Thank you

Comment: You made `age` a function. You need to call it: `if (this.age() < 18) {`

Comment: Damn, Extra pair of eyes. I missed adding the function and broke my head. It works as expected. Thank you

Comment: I would also recommend that you use a class instead of a function. Messing with prototypes looks worse and is harder to understand. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes